# MediatR library: following the DRY principle

Tags: c#, .net, dry, cqrs, mediatr

I use library [`MediatR`](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) in my `ASP.NET Core` application.
I have the following entity `Ad`:

```
public class Ad
{
    public Guid AdId { get; set; }
    public AdType AdType { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    // ...
}
public enum AdType
{
    TextAd,
    HtmlAd,
    BannerAd,
    VideoAd
}
```

I want to introduce the ability to create a new ad. To do so, I've created the following command:

```
public class CreateAdCommand : IRequest<Guid>
{
    public AdType AdType { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<CreateAdCommand, Guid>
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public Handler(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateAdCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var ad = new Ad {AdType = request.AdType, Cost = request.Cost, Content = request.Content};
            
            _context.Ads.Add(ad);
            _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return ad.AdId;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works great. But here is a huge problem: each ad-type has some additional logic to the ad creation process (e.g., when creating the ad of type `TextAd` we need to find the keywords in the content of the ad). The simplest solution is:

```
public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateAdCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var ad = new Ad {AdType = request.AdType, Cost = request.Cost, Content = request.Content};

    _context.Ads.Add(ad);
    _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    switch (request.AdType)
    {
        case AdType.TextAd:
            // Some additional logic here...
            break;
        case AdType.HtmlAd:
            // Some additional logic here...
            break;
        case AdType.BannerAd:
            // Some additional logic here...
            break;
        case AdType.VideoAd:
            // Some additional logic here...
            break;
    }

    return ad.AdId;
}
```

This solution violates the Open Closed Principle (when I create a new ad-type, I need to create a new `case` inside of `CreateAdCommand`).

I have another idea. I can create a separate command for each ad-type (e.g., `CreateTextAdCommand`, `CreateHtmlAdCommand`, `CreateBannerAdCommand`, `CreateVideoAdCommand`). This solution follows the Open Closed Principle (when I create a new ad-type, I need to create a new command for this ad-type - I don't need to change the existing code).

```
public class CreateTextAdCommand : IRequest<Guid>
{
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<CreateTextAdCommand, Guid>
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public Handler(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateTextAdCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var ad = new Ad {AdType = AdType.TextAd, Cost = request.Cost, Content = request.Content};

            _context.Ads.Add(ad);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            
            // Some additional logic here ...

            return ad.AdId;
        }
    }
}

public class CreateHtmlAdCommand : IRequest<Guid>
{
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<CreateHtmlAdCommand, Guid>
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public Handler(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateHtmlAdCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var ad = new Ad {AdType = AdType.HtmlAd, Cost = request.Cost, Content = request.Content};

            _context.Ads.Add(ad);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            
            // Some additional logic here ...

            return ad.AdId;
        }
    }
}

// The same for CreateBannerAdCommand and CreateVideoAdCommand.
```

This solution follows the Open Closed Principle, but violates the DRY principle. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a mechanism to share data across the pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you stick to your second approach, you can levarage MediatR 'Behaviors' (https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors). They act like pipelines, where you can offload common behavior into a commonly used handler.

To do this, create a marker interface

```
interface ICreateAdCommand {}
```

Now let each concreate command inherit from it

```
public class CreateTextAdCommand : ICreateAdCommand 
{
   public readonly string AdType {get;} = AdType.Text
}
public class CreateHtmltAdCommand : ICreateAdCommand 
{
   public readonly string AdType {get;} = AdType.Html
}
/*...*/
```

You could combine this or replace this with a common abstract base class, to avoid repetition of common properties. This is up to you.

Now we create the handler for our behavior:

```
public class CreateAdBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
where TReq : ICreateAdCommand
{
    public CreateAdBehavior()
    {
       //wire up dependencies.
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var ad = new Ad {AdType = request.AdType, Cost = request.Cost, Content = request.Content};

        _context.Ads.Add(ad);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //go on with the next step in the pipeline
        var response = await next();

        return response;
    }
}
```

Now wire up this behavior. In asp.net core this would be in your startup.cs

```
 services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(CreateAdBehavior<,>));
```

At this stage, everytime any of your `IRequests` implement `ICreateAdCommand`, it would automatically call the handler above and after this is done it would call the next behavior in line, or if there is none, the actual handler.

Your specific handler for, let's say a HtmlAd would now roughly look like this:

```
public class CreateHtmlAdCommand : IRequest<Guid>
{
    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<CreateHtmlAdCommand, Guid>
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public Handler(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateHtmlAdCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Some additional logic here ...
        }
    }
}
```

** Update **

If you want to drag data across the pipeline, you can leverage the actual request object.

```
public abstract class IRequestWithItems
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Items {get;} = new Dictionary<string,object>();
}
```

Now in your CreateAdBehavior, you can create your ad and store it in the dictionary, to retrieve it in the next handler:

```
var ad = { ... }
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
items["newlyCreatedAd"] = ad;
```

And in the actual `Task<Guid> Handle()` method, you have now the ad at your disposal, without looping back to your database to retrieve it again.

Details from the author: https://jimmybogard.com/sharing-context-in-mediatr-pipelines/

Comment: Thank you for the idea. But here is a problem - inside of `CreateAdBehavior` you create an ad, making its property `AdType` equal to `AdType.HtmlAd`. This means, that all ads will have type `AdType.HtmlAd`. Am I right?

Comment: You can set the type to request.AdType in the behavior if you pull the type property up to the ICreateAdCommand interface.

Comment: Yes, what @JonasHøgh said, is a suitable approach. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But what if another behavior in the pipeline will write into `items["newlyCreatedAd"]` another value? It looks a bit dirty. Maybe there is another way to pass the value from behavior to a command?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You'd have to be very careful, to not use the same variable name twice in a single behavior. Which should not be too hard, to be fair ;) But I'm glad it works for you. Feel free to mark it as solved

Comment: @Marco Wouldnt the Mediatr INotificationHandler work best/simpler for this scenario?

Comment: Might very well be. Feel free, to cobble something together and add it as an answer @sharpc